# Evolutive post about best sound design tutorials on the net?

Tags: discussion

I would like to create a post about best sound design tutorials
(this could be done by sound type)
you can find on the net and update the post regularly with the help of the community, is it possible to do that or is there a place elsewhere on Stack Overflow where I could do that?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You face a couple of problems with this concept:

- Best is always opinion based
- List questions are explicitly called out as not suitable here
- Stack Exchange is great for focused questions with specific answers, not so good for broad ranging things like tutorials
- Stack Exchange is not a great platform for answers which need continual updating

I'd suggest you create this list as a blog post instead, then anyone searching for it can find it through google.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just one point is I don't agree with your first point. "Best" can fulfil different criteria that can be measured objectively. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

That used to exist as a wonderful resource we called "Social Sound Design". I miss it terribly.

Comment: Come hang out with us at r/audiopost!  We need more active members and veterans such as yourself

Comment: I'll check it out!